# How to output results from a conditional statement to a MS Word file in Python?

Tags: python, if-statement

I have also been updating a Word file using the Python doc-x library and building tables etc into this file. Now I would like to add the results of the IF function.

```
if any(df.loc[df.loc[:,'Column A'] =='Y']):
        print (df.loc[:,'Value'] + "\n Placeholder A  \nPlaceholder B\n" +  str(table))
    else:
        print (df.loc[:,'Value'] + "\n Placeholder A \nPlaceholder B \n")
```

Any ideas on how I can achieve this? Currently, it is only printing the desired result to the console.

I have already tried using

```
doc.add_paragraph()
```

But there is no way to add in the conditional statement through this.

Comment: There is no "IF function" it's a statement exactly because it does not have a return value (that would be a function).  also what you mean by "add in the conditional statement" ? do you want to add the whole code block of just the strings that get printed in your snippet?

Comment: thanks for the edit and update. The block of strings that get printed is what I would like to be put into the word doc.

Comment: Well, in that case you could simply replace the print with doc.add_paragraph or a similar method from the doc-x lib.

Answer (score 0):

You can put python `if`/`else` inline:

```py
new_value = df.loc[:, 'Value'] + "\n Placeholder A  \nPlaceholder B\n" + (str(table) if any(df.loc[df.loc[:, 'Column A'] == 'Y']) else '')
```

So the if/else part gives either an empty string `''` to be added to the end, or `str(table)`

Next, just add `new_value` to your document.

Comment: Thanks, this is a much neater method. However, I get the error `The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().` any ideas as to why?

Comment: That depends. Which python version? What's `type(df.loc[:, 'Column A'])` ? Does `df.loc[:, 'Column A'] == 'Y'` execute by itself on its own line? You could try using `numpy.array_equal(df.loc[:, 'Column A'], 'Y')`.

Comment: Python v3.7. Both lines print the output in the Python console. Can't check if it is actually correct because some of the output is cut off due to console size. Type is `pandas.core.series.Series` The type for new_val is also the same. I tried to convert to string to be able to add the new_val to my doc but no avail!